# Subtract values with groupby in Pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe likes this:

| Alliance_name | Company_name | TOAD | MBA | Class | EVE | TBD | Sur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shinva group | HVC corp | 8845 | 1135 | 0 | 12 | 12128 | 1 |
| Shinva group | LDN corp | 11 | 1243 | 133 | 121 | 113 | 1 |
| Telegraph group | Freename LLC | 5487 | 223 | 928 | 0 | 0 | 21 |
| Telegraph group | Grt | 0 | 7543 | 24 | 3213 | 15 | 21 |
| Zero group | PetZoo crp | 5574 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 6478 | 1 |
| Zero group | Elephant | 48324 | 0 | 32 | 118 | 4 | 1 |

I need to subtract values between cells in the column if they have the same Alliance_name.
(it would be perfect not to subtract the last column Sur, but it is not the main target)

I know that for addition we can make something like this:

`df = df.groupby('Alliance_name').sum()`

But I don't know how to do this with subtraction.

The result should be like this (if we don't subtract the last column):

| Alliance_name | Company_name | TOAD | MBA | Class | EVE | TBD | Sur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Shinva group | HVC corp LDN corp | 8834 | -108 | -133 | -109 | 12015 | 1 |
| Telegraph group | Freename LLC Grt | 5487 | -7320 | 904 | -3212 | -15 | 21 |
| Zero group | PetZoo crp Elephant | -42750 | 0 | -30 | -118 | 6474 | 1 |

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could invert the values to subtract, and then sum them.

```
df.loc[df.Alliance_name.duplicated(keep="first"), ["TOAD", "MBA", "Class", "EVE", "TBD", "Sur"]] *= -1
df.groupby("Alliance_name").sum()
```

Comment: if we invert the values we will recieve -8845 and -11 in TOAD, for example. if we sum them we will get -8856. not 8834

Comment: I'm slicing the DataFrame and then inverting the values. `df.Alliance_name.duplicated(keep="first")` -> this will ensure the inverting operation is applied only to the second appearance of  an Alliance (considering there won't be more than two Alliances)

Answer (score 1):

The [`.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and `.last()` groupby methods can be useful for such tasks.

You can organize the columns you want to skip/compute

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['Alliance_name', 'Company_name', 'TOAD', 'MBA', 'Class', 'EVE', 'TBD',
   'Sur'],
  dtype='object')
>>> alliance, company, *cols, sur = df.columns
>>> groups = df.groupby(alliance)
>>> company = groups.first()[[company]]
>>> sur = groups.first()[sur]
>>> groups = groups[cols]
```

And use `.first() - .last()` directly:

```
>>> groups.first() - groups.last()
                  TOAD   MBA  Class   EVE    TBD
Alliance_name
Shinva group      8834  -108   -133  -109  12015
Telegraph group   5487 -7320    904 -3213    -15
Zero group      -42750     0    -30  -118   6474
```

Then `.join()` the other columns back in

```
>>> company.join(groups.first() - groups.last()).join(sur).reset_index()
     Alliance_name  Company_name   TOAD   MBA  Class   EVE    TBD  Sur
0     Shinva group      HVC corp   8834  -108   -133  -109  12015    1
1  Telegraph group  Freename LLC   5487 -7320    904 -3213    -15   21
2       Zero group    PetZoo crp -42750     0    -30  -118   6474    1
```

Another approach:

```
>>> df - df.drop(columns=['Company_name', 'Sur']) .groupby('Alliance_name').shift(-1)
   Alliance_name  Class  Company_name     EVE     MBA  Sur      TBD     TOAD
0            NaN -133.0           NaN  -109.0  -108.0  NaN  12015.0   8834.0
1            NaN    NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
2            NaN  904.0           NaN -3213.0 -7320.0  NaN    -15.0   5487.0
3            NaN    NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
4            NaN  -30.0           NaN  -118.0     0.0  NaN   6474.0 -42750.0
5            NaN    NaN           NaN     NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
```

You can then drop the all nan rows and fill the remainder values from the original df.

```
>>> ((df - df.drop(columns=['Company_name', 'Sur'])
             .groupby('Alliance_name').shift(-1)).dropna(how='all')[df.columns].fillna(df))
     Alliance_name  Company_name   TOAD   MBA  Class   EVE    TBD  Sur
0     Shinva group      HVC corp   8834  -108   -133  -109  12015    1
2  Telegraph group  Freename LLC   5487 -7320    904 -3213    -15   21
4       Zero group    PetZoo crp -42750     0    -30  -118   6474    1
```